# conda install fails even i found the package by conda info package

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I am on windows using Anaconda with python 3.5, I want to install opencv3.1, so I found a channel called conda-forge has the opencv3.2 for my python version, but when I try to install it by：

> conda install -c conda-forge opencv

I got error message:

```
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: ....
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv -> jpeg 9*
  - opencv -> numpy 1.9*
  - opencv -> python 2.7*|3.4*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

but when I do:

> conda info opencv

there is an opencv for python3.5, why conda cannot find it?

```
opencv 3.1.0 np111py35_1
------------------------
file name   : conda-forge::opencv-3.1.0-np111py35_1.tar.bz2
name        : opencv
version     : 3.1.0
build number: 1
build string: np111py35_1
channel     : conda-forge
size        : 84.4 MB
arch        : x86_64
binstar     : {'owner_id': '5528f42ce1dad12974506e8d', 'package_id': '56feac4e676dfa6a0572551e', 'channel': 'main'}
fn          : opencv-3.1.0-np111py35_1.tar.bz2
has_prefix  : True
license     : BSD 3-clause
machine     : x86_64
md5         : 9ff21915905c36894059eaf8d6d554cc
operatingsystem: win32
platform    : win
priority    : 1
schannel    : conda-forge
subdir      : win-64
target-triplet: x86_64-any-win32
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/opencv-3.1.0-np111py35_1.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    jpeg 9*
    libpng >=1.6.21,<1.7
    libtiff 4.0.*
    numpy 1.11*
    python 3.5*
    zlib 1.2.*
```

so I checked the env by `conda list` and I have:

```
λ conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\MPNV38\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:
#
_license                  1.1                      py35_1
_nb_ext_conf              0.3.0                    py35_0
alabaster                 0.7.9                    py35_0
anaconda                  4.2.0               np111py35_0
anaconda-clean            1.0.0                    py35_0
anaconda-client           1.5.1                    py35_0
anaconda-navigator        1.3.1                    py35_0
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1
astroid                   1.4.7                    py35_0
astropy                   1.2.1               np111py35_0
babel                     2.3.4                    py35_0
backports                 1.0                      py35_0
beautifulsoup4            4.5.1                    py35_0
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_1
blaze                     0.10.1                   py35_0
bokeh                     0.12.2                   py35_0
boto                      2.42.0                   py35_0
bottleneck                1.1.0               np111py35_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]
cffi                      1.7.0                    py35_0
chest                     0.2.3                    py35_0
click                     6.6                      py35_0
cloudpickle               0.2.1                    py35_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py35_0
colorama                  0.3.7                    py35_0
comtypes                  1.1.2                    py35_0
conda                     4.2.9                    py35_0
conda-build               2.0.3                    py35_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         0
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                    py35_1
contextlib2               0.5.3                    py35_0
cryptography              1.5                      py35_0
curl                      7.49.0                   vc14_0  [vc14]
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0
cython                    0.24.1                   py35_0
cytoolz                   0.8.0                    py35_0
dask                      0.11.0                   py35_0
datashape                 0.5.2                    py35_0
decorator                 4.0.10                   py35_0
dill                      0.2.5                    py35_0
docutils                  0.12                     py35_2
dynd-python               0.7.2                    py35_0
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py35_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py35_0
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_1
filelock                  2.0.6                    py35_0
flask                     0.11.1                   py35_0
flask-cors                2.1.2                    py35_0
freetype                  2.5.5                    vc14_1  [vc14]
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py35_0
gevent                    1.1.2                    py35_0
greenlet                  0.4.10                   py35_0
h5py                      2.6.0               np111py35_2
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                 vc14_4  [vc14]
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_1
icu                       57.1                     vc14_0  [vc14]
idna                      2.1                      py35_0
imagesize                 0.7.1                    py35_0
ipykernel                 4.5.0                    py35_0
ipython                   5.1.0                    py35_0
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0
ipywidgets                5.2.2                    py35_0
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0
jdcal                     1.2                      py35_1
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_1
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_1
jpeg                      8d                       vc14_2  [vc14]
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py35_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3
jupyter_client            4.4.0                    py35_0
jupyter_console           5.0.0                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.2.0                    py35_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.2.1                    py35_0
libdynd                   0.7.2                         0
libpng                    1.6.22                   vc14_0  [vc14]
libtiff                   4.0.6                    vc14_2  [vc14]
llvmlite                  0.13.0                   py35_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py35_1
lxml                      3.6.4                    py35_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2
matplotlib                1.5.3               np111py35_0
menuinst                  1.4.1                    py35_0
mistune                   0.7.3                    py35_0
mkl                       11.3.3                        1
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py35_2
mpmath                    0.19                     py35_1
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0
nb_anacondacloud          1.2.0                    py35_0
nb_conda                  2.0.0                    py35_0
nb_conda_kernels          2.0.0                    py35_0
nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py35_0
nbformat                  4.1.0                    py35_0
nbpresent                 3.0.2                    py35_0
networkx                  1.11                     py35_0
nltk                      3.2.1                    py35_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_1
notebook                  4.2.3                    py35_0
numba                     0.28.1              np111py35_0
numexpr                   2.6.1               np111py35_0
numpy                     1.11.1                   py35_1
odo                       0.5.0                    py35_1
openpyxl                  2.3.2                    py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2j                   vc14_0  [vc14]
pandas                    0.18.1              np111py35_0
partd                     0.3.6                    py35_0
path.py                   8.2.1                    py35_0
pathlib2                  2.1.0                    py35_0
patsy                     0.4.1                    py35_0
pep8                      1.7.0                    py35_0
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0
pillow                    3.3.1                    py35_0
pip                       8.1.2                    py35_0
pkginfo                   1.3.2                    py35_0
ply                       3.9                      py35_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.3                    py35_0
psutil                    4.3.1                    py35_0
py                        1.4.31                   py35_0
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_1
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_4
pycurl                    7.43.0                   py35_0
pyflakes                  1.3.0                    py35_0
pygments                  2.1.3                    py35_0
pylint                    1.5.4                    py35_1
pyopenssl                 16.0.0                   py35_0
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py35_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_0
pytables                  3.2.2               np111py35_4
pytest                    2.9.2                    py35_0
python                    3.5.2                         0
python-dateutil           2.5.3                    py35_0
pytz                      2016.6.1                 py35_0
pywin32                   220                      py35_1
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0
pyzmq                     15.4.0                   py35_0
qt                        5.6.0                    vc14_0  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.3.3                    py35_0
qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py35_2
qtpy                      1.1.2                    py35_0
requests                  2.11.1                   py35_0
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py35_0
scikit-image              0.12.3              np111py35_1
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py35_1
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_1
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_1
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py35_0
sip                       4.18                     py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py35_0
sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py35_0
sphinx                    1.4.6                    py35_0
spyder                    3.0.0                    py35_0
sqlalchemy                1.0.13                   py35_0
statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py35_1
sympy                     1.0                      py35_0
tk                        8.5.18                   vc14_0  [vc14]
toolz                     0.8.0                    py35_0
tornado                   4.4.1                    py35_0
traitlets                 4.3.0                    py35_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0
werkzeug                  0.11.11                  py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
widgetsnbextension        1.2.6                    py35_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py35_0
wrapt                     1.10.6                   py35_0
xlrd                      1.0.0                    py35_0
xlsxwriter                0.9.3                    py35_0
xlwings                   0.10.0                   py35_0
xlwt                      1.1.2                    py35_0
zlib                      1.2.8                    vc14_3  [vc14]
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `conda list`?

Comment: @Paul please see my post with updates. thanks!

Comment: This is likely the problem: `jpeg 8d vc14_2  [vc14]` You need at least `jpeg 9`, which apparently isn't available for your system/version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the link [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1074). As far as I understand, it is an issue related to the new version of anaconda. If you need to find a fast solution, you can simply create a virtual environment, activate the environment, and install opencv there.

The other solution is to simply use this command:

`conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0`